# Java swing - super.paintcomponent(g) - repaint()

Tags: java, swing

I have two classes like below, in MyPanel class I have overrided `paintComponent` method to add my own "drawings" to `JPanel` . I have called super.paintComponent(g)  because as far as i understand when I use my own implementation of inherited method I also override the standard "hidden" functionality of this method . I understand that if i want to use methods like setBackground/setBorder on the myPanel i have to call the paintComponent method from extended class to make it work in it's own standard way
(paint background, paint boarders etc).

So in my opinion every time when i press the mouse button I invoke my moveSquare method and it will invoke repaint method. When repaint method is called the program goes to the overrided paintComponent method. I know that when I use the

```
repaint(squareX, squareY, squareW, squareH);
```

in moveSquare method it will repaint only the red square (background will not be repainted) , and that's why i will see every red square on my panel . I know that if i would use repaint() in first call and then repaint with arguments like this :

```
                    repaint();
        squareX=x;
        squareY=y;
        repaint(squareX, squareY, squareW, squareH);
```

it will redraw the background and then draw a square , so i will be able to see only the last red painted square on my panel.What i dont understand is why double call of repaint method with arguments :

```
                    repaint(squareX, squareY, squareW, squareH);
        squareX=x;
        squareY=y;
        repaint(squareX, squareY, squareW, squareH);
```

will first draw a square with the color of background and then the red one (it will behave like i would call repaint without the arguments and then repaint with arguments).

Sorry for such long explanation , but i think it will be easier to point my mistke if
i will explain how i think it should work.

SwingMoveSquareDemo class

```
public class SwingMoveSquareDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

                    public void run(){
                        System.out.println("GUI started");
                        createGUI();

                    }

                    });


}

public static void createGUI(){

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Move square demo");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(new MyPanel());

    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);


}





}
```

MyPanel class

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

private int squareX=1;
private int squareY=1;
private int squareW=20;
private int squareH=20;

public MyPanel(){

    setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,250));


    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("mouspressed");
            moveSquare(e.getX(),e.getY());
        }
    });




}

private void moveSquare (int x, int y){


            repaint(squareX, squareY, squareW, squareH);
        squareX=x;
        squareY=y;
        repaint(squareX, squareY, squareW, squareH);





}   



public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);

    System.out.println("paint component");

    g.setColor(Color.RED);

    g.fillRect(squareX, squareY, squareW, squareH);


}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paintComponent` delegates to `ComponentUI#update`, which sets the `Graphics` context's color to the components background color and fills `0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight()` (where `c` is a reference to the component been painted).

Basically, what this means is, even if you use `repaint` or `repaint(x, y, width, height)`, the background is begin completely updated.

The difference is, the `Graphics` clip changes.  When calling `repaint`, the clip will be the size of the component, when using `repaint(x, y, width, height)`, the clip shape will be the same as those values you passed it.

You may want to take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details.

Remember, painting in Swing is under the control of the `RepaintManager`, it will decide what and when something should be painted.  When it decides that an update needs to take place, it will place a "paint" event onto the Event Queue, which will be processed, at some time in the future by the Event Dispatching Thread.  This means, that under most circumstances, painting is not immediate...

Comment: so if i understand you right when event queue handles both of those repaint(x,y,width,height) he  knows that the clips will be changed and he is smart enough to repaint background and skip fillRect in first repaint call, and do both of those operations in second repaint call?

Comment: By the time that the repaint is handled, you've already changed the `squareX` and `squareY` values.  The repaint won't occur until after the `mouseClicked` method has occured, as it is handled on by the EDT as well...

Comment: yes, but i still cant understand one thing, after mouseClicked two repaints are handled, both are the same (except the clips) , in my opinion it should paint background on the old clips (paintComponent call) , fillRect on the old clips. Next repaint should paint background on new clips (paintComponent call) , and fiLLRect on new clips , but instead of that , it's done like that :
     1st repaint(x,y,w,h) 
     paint background on x,y,w,h clips
     new x,y  
     2nd repaint (x,y,w,h)
     paint background on new x,y,w,h clips (or not?)
     paint rect on new x,y,w,h clips

Comment: Have you tried outputting the squareX and squareY values within the paintComponent method, I think you'll find that both calls will have the same value ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is because when you call `repaint()`, it doesn't happen immediately; it will be put onto the event dispatch thread and called later.  also if you call multiple repaints in succession, it may repaint the union of their rectangles.

So when you call repaint the first time, it will queue to draw the rectangle you specified. Then you update the coordinates of the square, and then you draw then you queue a repaint with the new rectangle.Then it combines the two and will draw the union of their rectangles.when the repaint is executed, the it will clear the background of the region and then draw the square.

insert `System.out.printf("dirty region = %s%n",g.getClipBounds());` in your `paintComponent ()` to see what rectangle is being drawn